# ComboBox error: Unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm trying to create dependable combobox in Excel VBA.

It is showing the error

> Unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class

```vb
Private Sub ErrorCategory_Change()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Category")
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ErrorCategory.Value, sh.Range("1:1"), 0)

Me.SubCategory.Clear
    For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(1, n).EntireColumn)
        Me.SubCategory.AddItem sh.Cells(i, n).Value
    Next i
     
End Sub
```

I get the error in the line

```vb
n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ErrorCategory.Value, sh.Range("1:1"), 0)
```

ErrorCategory is the name of the combobox.

Comment: That typically means there's no match for that value in that row.  If you use `Application.Match()` it will return an error value instead of raising a run-time error. (You need to `Dim n As Variant` in that case)  Test for error using `If IsError(n) Then`

Comment: Where should i do the changes, also I am not giving the value, instead there is other drop down to which this drop down is depended on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following from my comment above:

```
Private Sub ErrorCategory_Change()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Category")
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Variant, v

Me.SubCategory.Clear
v = Me.ErrorCategory.Value
n = Application.Match(v, sh.Range("1:1"), 0) 'no `WorksheetFunction`

If Not  IsError(n) Then  'check for match
    For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(1, n).EntireColumn)
        Me.SubCategory.AddItem sh.Cells(i, n).Value
    Next i    
Else
    Msgbox "no match found for '" & v & "'"
End if
 
End Sub
```

If it's not making a match then please provide more info about what types of values you're trying to match (date? Text? number?)

Comment: Thanks for the Help, I figured it out I gave the combo box text as select in properties which caused this error now it's working fine. Thanks again for help.